# Pytorch lightning validation set has different image sizes than training set

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, dataloader, pytorch-lightning

When i try to train a cnn, I get different shapes for the same dataloader and i dont know why. This is the output of the shapes I feed into the model:
[image]

You can see that my validation shape is [batch size, 1, image height and width]. for some reason, the image size gets changed in the last step and the batch size is 1. The same happens when I use the sanity check from pytorch lightning beforehand, which ive disabled for now. This is how the pytorch lightning data module looks like which gets the dataloader:

```
class MRIDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
    def __init__(self, batch_size, data_paths):
        super().__init__()
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.data_paths = data_paths
        self.train_set = None
        self.val_set = None

    def setup(self, stage=None):
        loader = get_data_loader()
        self.train_set = loader(self.data_paths['train_dir'], transform=None, dimension=DIMENSION, nslice=NSLICE)
        self.val_set = loader(self.data_paths['val_dir'], transform=None, dimension=DIMENSION, nslice=NSLICE)

    def train_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.train_set, batch_size=self.batch_size, num_workers=NUM_WORKERS, shuffle=True)

    def val_dataloader(self):
        return DataLoader(self.val_set, batch_size=self.batch_size, num_workers=NUM_WORKERS, shuffle=False)
```

here is the full code and the print statements are directly from the forward function of my model:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1yfbCZlwNMqaW1egaTF8HHRD4Ko8iMTxr?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you add the code where you have introduced the print statements? As well as the initialization of your `MRIDataModule` module?

Comment: @Ivan added it as a google colab file, its in the train/val step of pytorch lightning and in my forward function of my model

Comment: Good, but please include the relevant code here instead of the full code. Also provide the parameters used to initialize `MRIDataModule`.

Answer (score 0):

I inspected you code and found the following:

```py
def validation_epoch_end(self, val_step_outputs):
        dummy_input = torch.zeros((1, 1, 150,150), device = device)
        model_filename = CONFIG['MODEL'] + "-DIM" + str(CONFIG["DIMENSION"]) + "-model_final.onnx"
        torch.onnx.export(self.net.eval(), dummy_input, model_filename)
```

This piece of code will be called every time your validation epoch is over. Which means that you will pass your `dummy_input` of size `(1, 1, 150,150)` to the model. That is why your are seeing a different images shape for the last validation step, than your batches coming from your dataloader